# Require Integer Value not Memory Address whilst avoiding Invalid receiver type compiler warning

Tags: objective-c, int, compiler-warnings

I have the following code;

```
int days = [[SettingsUtils daysToRetainHistory] intValue];
[retainHistory setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Days to retain History: %d", days]];
[daysToRetainHistory setValue:days animated:NO];
```

where `[SettingsUtils daysToRetainHistory]` is as follows;

```
+ (int) daysToRetainHistory {
    return (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CaseBaseDaysToRetainHistory"];
}
```

I get the compiler warning `Invalid receiver type 'int'` because I call `intValue` on an `int` but unless I do this I can't seem to get the integer value out and always end up with the memory address i.e. 98765432 instead of 9 which ruins the UILabel display [`retainHistory`] and the UISlider [`daysToRetainHistory`] value.

How do I avoid the compiler warning and still get my integer value in the label and the necessary float value for setting the UISlider value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are casting a memory address to an int that int value isn't working. Instead just use the method you want from NSUserDefaults:

```
+ (NSInteger)daysToRetainHistory
{
  return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CaseBaseDaysToRetainHistory"];
}
```

then just use it directly:

```
NSInteger days = [SettingsUtils daysToRetainHistory];
```

You should also store your days with the same method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:days forKey:@"CaseBaseDaysToRetainHistory"];
```

Although if you set the NSNumber object and it actually does contain an integer, that will work fine too.